# Animation in Cocos2d.

Tags: iphone, animation, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I am trying to make a `sprite animate` in `cocos2D`.  I believe I have the animation set up, but how do I draw the `animating sprite` onto the screen?  Here is what I have:

```
id anim = [[[CCAnimation alloc] initWithName:@"char_walking" delay:1/12.0] autorelease];

[anim addFrame:@"run2.png"];
[anim addFrame:@"run1.png"];
[anim addFrame:@"run3.png"];
[anim addFrame:@"run4.png"];
[anim addFrame:@"run3.png"];
[anim addFrame:@"run1.png"];

id myAction = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:anim];
id repeating = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:myAction];

[character do:repeating];

character = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrame:anim];
character.position = ccp(160, 240);
[self addChild:character];
```

Thanks in advance,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it was just a cut-and-paste error, but it looks like you're telling the sprite to repeat the animation BEFORE you create it, so the character sprite you are adding to the node never gets the CCAnimate action sent to it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding spriteFrames as the addFrame method requires.

with this line:

> [character do:repeating];

maybe you're looking for `[character runAction:repeating];`

> character = [CCSprite
>   spriteWithSpriteFrame:anim];

Here, anim is not a spriteFrame, it's a CCanimation.

basically, you have a few problems.

you could try something like this using [zwoptex](http://zwoptexapp.com/flashversion/) to create your .plist file:

```
CCSpriteFrameCache *cache = [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]; 

[cache addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"runImages.plist"]; 

CCSprite *startingImage = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"run1.png"];

[self addChild:startingImage];
```

//create your sprite frames

```
NSArray *animFrames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithCapacity:6];

[animFrames addFrame:[cache spriteFrameByName:@"run2.png"]];
[animFrames addFrame:[cache spriteFrameByName:@"run1.png"]];
[animFrames addFrame:[cache spriteFrameByName:@"run3.png"]];
[animFrames addFrame:[cache spriteFrameByName:@"run4.png"]];
[animFrames addFrame:[cache spriteFrameByName:@"run3.png"]];
[animFrames addFrame:[cache spriteFrameByName:@"run1.png"]];
```

//run the animation

```
CCAnimation *animation = [CCAnimation animationWithName:@"char_walking" delay:1/12.0 frames:animFrames];
id anim = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation restoreOriginalFrame:NO];    
[startingImage runAction:anim];
```